# How to fire a command when picker's selected item changes

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding

I'm trying to fire a `Command` in my `ViewModel` when the selected item changes, passing the whole object as parameter. The `SelectedCondicaoPagamento` is the default value. How can I do that?

the `Model`

```
public class CaptacaoPedidoItem : Notifier
{
    //displays all 'CondicaoPagamento'
    public List<CondicaoPagamento> CondicoesPagamento { get; set; }

    private CondicaoPagamento _selectedCondicaoPagamento;

    public CondicaoPagamento SelectedCondicaoPagamento
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCondicaoPagamento;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedCondicaoPagamento= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

the `ViewModel`

```
 public class CaptacaoViewModel : Notifier
 {
    public Command PlanoPagamentoAlteradoCommand => new Command(PlanoPagamentoAlterado);
    public List<CaptacaoPedidoItem> ItensPedido
    {
        get
        {
            return _itensPedido;
        }
        set
        {
            _itensPedido = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    //it's not called
    public void PlanoPagamentoAlterado()
    {

    }
 }
```

the `View`

```
<ListView  Grid.Row="3"  x:Name="listasugestao" ItemsSource="{Binding ItensPedido}" RowHeight="80">
   {...}
   <Picker   
    ItemsSource="{Binding CondicoesPagamento}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCondicaoPagamento}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding NomePlanoPagamento}"
    Grid.Column="6" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Picker.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior EventName="SelectedIndexChanged">
                <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PlanoPagamentoAlteradoCommand}" />
            </behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior>
        </Picker.Behaviors>
    </Picker>

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses the [reusable EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior) published by Microsoft.
I took the liberty of also sending the viewmodel object bound to the respective cellview as a command parameter. That way it is easy to find out in what cell of your list actually changed.

### View

```
<Picker   
    ItemsSource="{Binding CondicoesPagamento}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCondicaoPagamento}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding NomePlanoPagamento}"
    Grid.Column="6" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    
    <Picker.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior 
                EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" 
                Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PlanoPagamentoAlteradoCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=listasugestao}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </Picker.Behaviors>
                                
</Picker>
```

### ViewModel

```
public class CaptacaoViewModel : Notifier
{
    public CaptacaoViewModel()
    {
        PlanoPagamentoAlteradoCommand = new Command<CaptacaoPedidoItem>(WhenSelectedIndexChanged);
    }
 
    public Command PlanoPagamentoAlteradoCommand {get;}
    
    public List<CaptacaoPedidoItem> ItensPedido
    {
        get
        {
            return _itensPedido;
        }
        set
        {
            _itensPedido = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    
    private void WhenSelectedIndexChanged(CaptacaoPedidoItem item)
    {
        // do something
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this implementing the flowing converter.

Create the `BehaviorBase` class:

```cs
public class BehaviorBase<T>: Behavior<T> where T : BindableObject  
{  
    public T AssociatedObject { get; private set; }  
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(T bindable)  
    {  
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);  
        AssociatedObject = bindable;  

        if (bindable.BindingContext != null)  
            BindingContext = bindable.BindingContext;  

        bindable.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;  
    }  
    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(T bindable)  
    {  
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);  
        bindable.BindingContextChanged -= OnBindingContextChanged;  
        AssociatedObject = null;  
    }  

    void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        OnBindingContextChanged();  
    }  

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()  
    {  
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();  
        BindingContext = AssociatedObject.BindingContext;  
    }  
}
```

Create the `EventToCommandBehavior` class:

```cs
public class EventToCommandBehavior: BehaviorBase<VisualElement>  
{
    private Delegate _eventHandler;  
    public static readonly BindableProperty EventNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create("EventName", typeof(string), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null, propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged);  
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior));  

    public string EventName  
    {  
        get => (string)GetValue(EventNameProperty);
        set => SetValue(EventNameProperty, value);
    }  
    public ICommand Command  
    {  
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }  

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(VisualElement bindable)  
    {  
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);  
        RegisterEvent(EventName);  
    }  

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(VisualElement bindable)  
    {  
        DeregisterEvent(EventName);  
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);  
    }

    private static void OnEventNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)  
    {  
        var behavior = (EventToCommandBehavior)bindable;  

        if (behavior.AssociatedObject == null) return;  

        var oldEventName = (string)oldValue;  
        var newEventName = (string)newValue;  

        behavior.DeregisterEvent(oldEventName);  
        behavior.RegisterEvent(newEventName);  
    }

    private void RegisterEvent(string name)  
    {  
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) return;  

        var eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);  

        if (eventInfo == null)  
            throw new ArgumentException($"EventToCommandBehavior: Can't register the '{EventName}' event.");  

        var methodInfo = typeof(EventToCommandBehavior).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("OnEvent");  
        _eventHandler = methodInfo.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this);  
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(AssociatedObject, _eventHandler);  
    }

    private void DeregisterEvent(string name)  
    {  
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || _eventHandler == null)  
            return;  

        var eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);  

        if (eventInfo == null)  
            throw new ArgumentException($"EventToCommandBehavior: Can't de-register the '{EventName}' event.");  

        eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(AssociatedObject, _eventHandler);  
        _eventHandler = null;  
    }

    private void OnEvent(object sender, object eventArgs)  
    {  
        if (Command == null) return;
    
        if (Command.CanExecute(eventArgs))  
            Command.Execute(eventArgs);  
    }
}
```

Add the custom behavior to your `Picker`:

```xml
<Picker Title="My picker"
        AutomationProperties.Name="some picker to do something"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding DataSelected}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}">
    <Picker.Behaviors>
        <behaviour:EventToCommandBehavior 
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" 
            Command="{Binding SomeDataSelectedCommand}"
        />
    </Picker.Behaviors>
</Picker>
```

This method also work for others type of view component, the following example uses the event to command converter to get `Appearing` and `Disappearing` events form `ContentPage`:

```xml
<ContentPage ...>
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Appearing" Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}"/>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Disappearing" Command="{Binding DisappearingCommand}"/>
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Some stuff here" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Resource:** https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-eventtocommand-behavior-in-mvvm-viewmodel/